# File used by another process asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, asynchronous

I have developed a website in asp.net mvc that reads from a xml-file to display some data. This file is regularly updated by my backend process that builds this xml-file and finally uploads it to my webhost via ftp.

This have been working fine, but in the last week or so I have gotten into a problem. I get the asp.net exception "file is being used by another process". I have no clue what this can be, and I find it very odd. I haven't even changed anything in my code for some months now.

Below you will find a typical method that I use for serializing my xml-file:

```
    public static IEnumerable<FStreamObject> GetStreams()
    {

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath+"/ff.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlReader ffXML = XmlReader.Create(fs);

            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FXmlModel));

            var sList = (FXmlModel)ser.Deserialize(ffXML);

            fs.Close();

            return sList.FSObjectList.OrderByDescending(x => x.Cash);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You can use Process Explorer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx to find which process uses your file (http://windowsxp.mvps.org/processlock.htm)

Comment: +1 to ProcessExplorer. Will save you a lot of time in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the other process which updates the content of your file still has a lock on this file. So you may need to fix the code of that to make sure you are releasing any locks /connection to this file once you are done with the file operations.

Comment: This does not seem to be the problem. The problem must be at my webhost. I can turn my server off that updates this file, and I still have the same problem, even if I manually update the file. It must be some design errors in my asp.net mvc code.

Comment: @JamesFord : Since you are using the `using` block, I do not think you are doing a file lock in your code .the using block will take care if it (call to Dispose to free the memory). So it should be a problem with the other proc.

Comment: I have tried to locate the problem for some time now. It seems that you are correct. Somehow my process got a lock on the file. Seems like it is working now with some changes. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that an Exception is being thrown before the fs.Close() invocation.
Try using a try-catch-fianlly and put the fs.Close() in the finally block.

Also have in mind the Close() method is not destroying the object immediately, you could also try using Dispose() to be sure the reference is being cleaned from memory.

Hope it helps!

Comment: using block should close stream even if exception is thrown, so fs.Close() is not needed.

Comment: @Giedrius you are right. There's an exception to that rule when a thread is forced to abort...but my code will be also useless if that happens ;)